# models.py not getting generated when using the inspectdb

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate models.py  from a legacy database using the inspectdb command. Everything was fine, i see the table names being inspected and corresonding classes made in the console, after that operation is completed, I checked the directory where the manage.py is residing, and there was no models.py generated.

Can anyone throw some light on this?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [inspectdb command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) does not automatically create a models.py file, by default it outputs the models to the console.

You can save the output to a file on Unix systems with

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

**Note this will overwrite `models.py` if it already exists!**

Comment: For appending to an existing file (say `models.py` already exists) you can use `>>` instead of `>` (thus `... inspectdb >> models.py`).